# Spring batch to process millions of records issue in performance

Tags: spring, spring-batch, partitioning

I want to read 4000 records from table (of 40 million records), make 4000 parallel rest api calls in processor, write them back to another database. Then fetch next 4000 records, process and write to DB untill 40 million is reached. Can you share the best approach for this?
So far I have tried two approaches,

1. With partitioner. This works best w.r.t parallel rest api calls in the processor but fails in writer step as most of the threads wait for db connection which gets timed out
2. With asynchronous processor and writer. Only ten threads are being generated which makes 10 rest api calls at a time which is consuming lot of time. Writer is one step and that is quick. I have tried increasing the throttle. limit but not like making 4000 parallel calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options are suitable to your requirement IMO, and in both cases the issue is NOT related to Spring Batch:

1. you are bound by your database resources: you should adapt your database settings to accept 4000 concurrent write operations
2. you are bound by the task executor resources: you should use a pool-based `TaskExecutor` that is able to handle 4000 concurrent tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In approach2, I currently return Future to the writer. Can I return CompletableFuture instead?